# Display calendar control with week number and capture week number when user selects and display in textbox

Tags: asp.net, calendar, controls

I am using a Ajax calendar control to pop up calendar from text box, want to display the week number in the calendar control itself, after user selects a week in the week mode (SelectionMode="DayWeek"), would like to display that week number in the text box. Preferably looking to implement using asp.net calendar control not jQuery.

Appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you've currently got? If you're using the Ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender control (for Textboxes), the textbox should be automatically populated with the formatted date (in your case week number)

Comment: To me that code looks perfectly fine - I would happily use that if I were you. Post your solution as an answer and mark as as correct for other people to see. The only question is why do you prefer that it be an ASP.NET control?

Comment: In html5 you can use a `<asp:textbox>` whit `textmode=week` you can get the week without problem. It has the calendar but the problem is that only a browser that support html5 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought not to use the jquery, due to the ease and so many folks having solution out there i found the solution.
http://jsbin.com/eliki/16/
one of the issue is the the SQL server week (mostly in US) starts from Sunday, but  iso8601Week starts from Monday, I did work around this by placing the weekend towards the end and disabling. Let me know what you think of the solution or have better solution out there.

http://jsbin.com/eliki/16/

Ujjwal